# Using Variable as a column in sql query

Tags: java, mysql

Here is my code. **I am trying to use a variable instead of a column name in here**
[image: I am trying to use a variable instead of a column name in here]

**But I get below exception**. How can I resolve this error?
[image]

Comment: Please post code and exceptions as text, not images, and not in links.

Comment: String query3="UPDATE report SET '"+r.getItemno()+"'="+dqty+"";
        pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query3);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        }

Comment: Exception->>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''7068-0001-01-F'=0' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind table/column names in a prepared statement, nor would you normally want to allow this.  Here is a working version of your code:

```
String query = "UPDATE report SET itemno = ?";
pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setInt(1, dqty);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Notes:

You almost certainly want to add a `WHERE` clause to your update, without which it would affect every record in the table.  With prepared statements, you don't need to worry about escaping your literal data.  Just let Java handle this for you.

If you really need the ability to update other table/column combinations, then just create other statements for that.  One size fits all works at 7-Eleven, but not JDBC, since you might SQL injected.

Comment: This works for me.                                                                         
String query3="UPDATE report SET `"+r.getItemno()+"`=? WHERE Date='"+r.getDate()+"'";
pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query3);
pst.setInt(1, dqty);
pst.executeUpdate();
}

Comment: @M.B.Nadeeshan It works, but that doesn't mean it is ideal.  Concatenating SQL queries in Java is a bad thing, most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications tim.It's really worthful.